# Suppose that $X \to Y$ is a flat map of $\mathbb{C}$ schemes... pullback on cohomology vs. scheme theoretic preimages?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology, complex-geometry, sheaf-cohomology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be varieties over $\mathbb{C}$, assumed projective and smooth. Suppose that $f : X \to Y$ is flat morphism. For any subscheme $W$ denote its fundamental class by $[W]$.

Then for any subvariety $Z \subset Y$, we can compute the scheme theoretic preimage $f^{-1}(Z)$. It can be non-reduced, non-irreducible in general, but it defines a homology class in $X$ by linearity (reduced varieties define fundamental classes by triangulation). Denote this

One can also find a cohomology class in $Y$ that is dual to the cohomology class of $Z$, $PD[Z]$ (poincare dual).

The following should be true, I hope:

$PD (f^* PD ([Z])) = [f^{-1}(Z)]$.

I am lost for how to prove this, even in the case that $Z$ is a point.

Flatness is necessary, I think, since for the map $\pi: Bl_p P^2 \to P^2$, $\pi^{-1}(p)$ and $\pi^{-1}(q)$ have different classes in homology. (For example because their self intersection numbers are different, and the intersection pairing is defined on homology.)

Comment: I think you're essentially asking whether flat bullback (in the sense of chow rings) commutes with taking fundamental classes--correct? This is for singular cohomology, correct? This is certainly proven in, for example, Voisin's text. Have you looked there?

Comment: @AlexYoucis I haven't checked, I'll take a look. Thanks.